# C#: SQL Query Builder Class

Tags: c#, mysql

Where can I find a good SQL Query builder class. I just need a simple class to build a SQL string and that is it. I will need it for C# and MySql. I really don't need anything like Linq or NHibernate. Thanks

Comment: when you mean Sql Query Builder class, what are you expecting this class to do?

Comment: I am expecting the class to generate a SQL string. Similar to this class  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SelectQueryBuilder.aspx?msg=2461496

Answer (score 21):

Since Google leads me to this page,
I would suggest [SqlKata](https://sqlkata.com), a simple but powerful SqlQuery Builder, that supports nested where conditions, subqueries and joins.

Currently it supports SqlServer, MySql and PostgreSql

```
var query = new Query("Users")
     .LeftJoin("Countries", "Users.CountryId", "Countries.Id")
     .Where("Status", "blocked")
     .OrWhereIn("Id", new [] {10, 11, 12})
     .OrWhere("LastLogin", ">", DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-5));
```

**Note:** I am the owner of it

Difference between different compilers output
**MySql:** https://sqlkata.com/playground/mysql?code=var%20query%20=%20new%20Query(%22Posts%22).Limit(10).Offset(20)%3B

**SqlServer:** https://sqlkata.com/playground/sqlserver?code=var%20query%20=%20new%20Query(%22Posts%22).Limit(10).Offset(20)%3B

**Oracle:** https://sqlkata.com/playground/oracle?code=var%20query%20=%20new%20Query(%22Posts%22).Limit(10).Offset(20)%3B

Comment: It's an interesting intellectual exercise, but I'm wondering why one would do this instead of just writing parameterized SQL directly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Dealing with objects is way easier than dealing with strings, also you can benefit from the database abstraction layer, for example check http://sqlkata.vivida-apps.com/?sql--sqlsrv#offset and http://sqlkata.vivida-apps.com/?sql--mysql#offset

Comment: can it be used/ported it in .net 2.0

Comment: I am looking for a way to create tables on the fly. On a webpage a user can create a object (for example TodoItem) and add fields for this object (Responsible, dueDate, enumerations (isDone, isOpen, isInProgress)). The webpage shall post all these as a string to the server and the server should create a table with matching columns. Knex.js can do this [createTable](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-createTable) and [table.string](http://knexjs.org/#Schema-Building) . `table.string('Title', [150])` would add a column named Title with the length 150.

Answer (score 3):

I use this code..It Escapes the strings too i hope it Helps:

```
 class Mysql
{
    public static string INSERT(string INTO, NameValueCollection VALUES)
    {
        string queryString = "INSERT INTO " + INTO + " (";
        for (int i = 0; i < VALUES.Count; i++)
        {
            queryString += VALUES.Keys[i] + (i + 1 == VALUES.Count ? "" : ",");
        }
        queryString += ") VALUES (";

        for (int i = 0; i < VALUES.Count; i++)
        {
            queryString += Escape(VALUES[VALUES.Keys[i]]) + (i + 1 == VALUES.Count ? ("") : (","));
        }
        queryString += ");";
        return queryString;
    }
    public static string DELETE(string FROM, NameValueCollection WHERE)
    {

        string queryString = "DELETE FROM " + FROM + " WHERE";
        for (int i = 0; i < WHERE.Count; i++)
        {
            queryString += " " + WHERE.Keys[i] + "=" + Escape(WHERE[WHERE.Keys[i]]);

        }

        queryString += ";";
        return queryString;
    }
    public static string UPDATE(string UPDATE, NameValueCollection SET, NameValueCollection WHERE)
    {

        string queryString = "UPDATE " + UPDATE + " SET";
        for (int i = 0; i < SET.Count; i++)
        {
            queryString += " " + SET.Keys[i] + "=" + data.Escape(SET[SET.Keys[i]]) + (i + 1 == SET.Count ? ("") : (","));

        }
        queryString += " WHERE";
        for (int i = 0; i < WHERE.Count; i++)
        {
            queryString += " " + WHERE.Keys[i] + "=" + data.Escape(WHERE[WHERE.Keys[i]]);

        }
        queryString += ";";
        return queryString;

    }
    public static string SELECT(string[] SELECT, string FROM, NameValueCollection WHERE)
    {

        string queryString = "SELECT ";

        for (int i = 0; i < SELECT.Length; i++)
        {
            queryString += SELECT[i] + (i + 1 == SELECT.Length ? ("") : (","));

        }
        queryString += " FROM " + FROM + " WHERE ";
        for (int i = 0; i < WHERE.Count; i++)
        {
            queryString += " " + WHERE.Keys[i] + "=" + Escape(WHERE[WHERE.Keys[i]]);

        }

        queryString += ";";
        return queryString;

    }
    public static string Escape(string input)
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp"))
            {
                provider.GenerateCodeFromExpression(new CodePrimitiveExpression(input), writer, null);
                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You use it like this:

```
        NameValueCollection nvc_for_SET_and_VALUES=new NameValueCollection();
        NameValueCollection nvc_for_WHERE= new NameValueCollection();
        nvc_for_WHERE.Add("arg1","value1");
        nvc_for_WHERE.Add("AND arg2","value2");
        nvc_for_WHERE.Add("OR arg2","value3");
        nvc_for_SET_and_VALUES.Add("arg", "value");
        nvc_for_SET_and_VALUES.Add("arg2", "value2");
        string[] fieldsToSelect= { "arg1", "arg2" };
        Mysql.DELETE("mytable", nvc_for_WHERE);
        Mysql.INSERT("mytable", nvc_for_SET_and_VALUES);
        Mysql.SELECT(fieldsToSelect, "mytable", nvc_for_WHERE);
        Mysql.UPDATE("mytable", nvc_for_SET_and_VALUES, nvc_for_WHERE);
```

Comment: I'm almost crying, DON'T use string concatenation to build your queries, use the Command and Parameter objects instead. This is a possible vulnerability for SQL injection. http://www.imperva.com/resources/glossary/sql_injection.html

Comment: This code claims to be sanitized from SQL injection attacks, but I'm not at all sure how that sanitization works.  I don't see how building a C# expression from the parameter and then running it through CodeDom makes it sanitary.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use the framework class CommandBuilder. Check out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf579hcz.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 4 and don't mind using dynamics you can use [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive), created by Rob Conery, this single file Database requires no dlls, just drop the Massive.cs file and you ready to go.

You can use the Massive to build queries like this.

```
//grab all the products
var products = table.All();
//Or
var productsFour = table.All(columns: "ProductName as Name", where: "WHERE categoryID=@0",args: 4);
```

You can also run ad-hoc queries as needed:

```
var result = tbl.Query("SELECT * FROM Categories");
```

Comment: Hi Jethro, I looked in the documentation and did not see that it supports MySql. Do you know if they support MySql?

Comment: @Luke101, it seems that the original Massive didn't support MySql, but if you check this link http://nyqui.st/massive-data-access-for-mysql you will see someone has already added the functionallity to use MySql. :) You can use NuGet and look for Massive.MySql

Answer (score 2):

Mohammed Hadi, with [DbExtensions](http://maxtoroq.github.io/DbExtensions/) your sample can be like this:

```
    public static string InsertQuery(string into, NameValueCollection values)
    {
        var query = SQL
            .INSERT_INTO(into + " (" +
                         String.Join(" ,", values.Keys.Cast<String>().ToArray()) + 
                         ")")
            .VALUES(values.Keys.Cast<String>().Select(key => values[key]));

        return query.ToString();
    }
```