# C# Trying to develop an SQL query builder (like a string builder), 2 condition `Where`'s do not work

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, ms-access, stringbuilder

First, I must note, I'm using an Access database so SQL specific stuff have to be reconsidered, but mostly I note this because I'm aware that parameters for Access must be ordered? Instead of defining VALUES, you would use something like ? ? ? ? ? etc.

I wonder that because I'm trying to build a query builder for my user so that he can use powerful commands only available in sql when interfacing with data. For now, I'm trying to do a simple SQL select, with a multi condition where.

I'm aware of SQL injection, so after the query is built, I still punch it through command parameters. Before I proceed further in this direction, I have to ask, am I on the right track? Is there an easier way to build this SQL query builder? As I mentioned, Access may have an issue wherein the parameters must be ordered. How will I get around this if my parameters are possibly optional?

The user writes into a textbox, selects their criteria from a combobox, then presses a button when it's done. This is how it goes:

1. List string sbuilder contains my query

   ```
       sbuilder.Append("Select * FROM ").Append(Current_Table).Append(" WHERE ");
   ```
2. This is an example of how they build it by interfacing with my UI

   ```
       foreach (Control c in tableLayoutPanel1.Controls)
       {
           if (c is TextBox)
           {
               TextBox textBox = c as TextBox;
               if (textBox.Text != string.Empty)
               {
                   switch (textBox.Name)
                   {
                       case "FilterAccount":
                           if (panelAccount.BackColor == Color.GreenYellow) {
                               DictionaryFindFilter(1, theDictionary.FilterHandler);
                               FilterAccount.Text = FilterReplacer(Acc);
                               sbuilder.Append("Account").Append(ComboBoxer(cmbAccount)).Append("@Account");
                               loops--;
                               if (loops >0) { sbuilder.Append(" AND "); }
                           }
                           break;
   ```

There's room for improvement here, but the important part is the sbuilder Append. Syntax can look like the following:

```
 `Select * FROM ACTB_CDSD WHERE Status_Regime = @Status`
```

Or with two conditions: 
     `Select * FROM ACTB_CDSD WHERE Status_Regime = @Status AND Account=@Account`

The two conditions thing doesn't work however. My table has more columns than these two, so the query will have to somehow accept these conditions out of order, which is probably what I need help with.

3. Here is what I punch the query into:

   ```
       using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(Con))
       {
           connection.Open();
           string query = sbuilder.ToString();
           OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection);
           da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Clear();
           da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IS", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FilterAccount.Text;
           da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FilterDept.Text;
           da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FilterStatus.Text;
           da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FilterProj.Text;
           da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USP", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FilterUSP.Text;
           da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PSP", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FilterPSP.Text;
           da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Period", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FilterPeriod.Text;
           da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FilterYear.Text;
           da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = FilterAccount.Text;
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           da.Fill(dt);
           DGVMain.DataSource = dt;
           connection.Close();
       }
   ```

With a single parameter, the code works, when I add another one which has the and, it no longer works.

As a bonus, I'd like to hear your opinions or suggestions on how to create a similar query builder like this one. The combobox contains criteria like `EQUAL TO` or `BETWEEN` or `LIKE`, which are other possibilities for my code above at point #2. I don't know if this is the best way to do this though, I saw this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172008/c-sql-query-builder-class) and liked how he built a class for it, but a commenter denied it, should I adopt a similar stance?